# The best way to mark (split?) dataset in each string

Tags: python, r, string, split, dataset

I have a dataset containing 485k strings (1.1 GB).
Each string contains about 700 of chars featuring about 250 variables (1-16 chars per variable), but it doesn't have any splitmarks. Lengths of each variable are known. What is the best way to modify and mark the data by symbol `,`?

---

For example:
I have strings like:

```
0123456789012...
1234567890123...
```

and array of lengths:
`5,3,1,4,...`
then I should get like this:

```
01234,567,8,9012,...
12345,678,9,0123,...
```

Could anyone help me with this? Python or R-tools are mostly preferred to me...

Comment: A similar option in `R` would be `read.fwf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) could load this using [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html#pandas.read_fwf):

```
In [321]:

t="""0123456789012..."""
pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(t), widths=[5,3,1,4], header=None)
Out[321]:
      0    1  2     3
0  1234  567  8  9012
```

This will give you a dataframe allowing you to access each individual column for whatever purpose you require

Answer (score 1):

In R `read.fwf` would work:

```
# inputs
x <- c("0123456789012...", "1234567890123... ")
widths <- c(5,3,1,4)

read.fwf(textConnection(x), widths, colClasses = "character")
```

giving:

```
     V1  V2 V3   V4
1 01234 567  8 9012
2 12345 678  9 0123
```

If numeric rather than character columns were desired then drop the `colClasses` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in R:

```
x <- "0123456789012"

y <- c(5,3,1,4)

output <- paste(substring(x,c(1,cumsum(y)+1),cumsum(y)),sep=",")
output <- output[-length(output)]
```

Answer (score 0):

One option in R is

```
indx1 <- c(1, cumsum(len)[-length(len)]+1)
indx2 <- cumsum(len)
toString(vapply(seq_along(len), function(i)
         substr(str1, indx1[i], indx2[i]), character(1)))
#[1] "01234, 567, 8, 9012"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- '0123456789012'
len <- c(5,3,1,4)
```