# Chunking, processing & merging dataset in Pandas/Python

Tags: python, pandas, merge, dataset, chunking

There is a large dataset, containing a strings.
I just want to open it via read_fwf using widths, like this:

```
widths = [3, 7, ..., 9, 7]
tp = pandas.read_fwf(file, widths=widths, header=None)
```

It would help me to [mark the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29800023/the-best-way-to-mark-split-dataset-in-each-string),
But the system crashes (works with nrows=20000). Then I decided to do it by chunk (e.g. 20000 rows), like this:

```
cs = 20000
for chunk in pd.read_fwf(file, widths=widths, header=None, chunksize=ch)
...:  <some code using chunk>
```

My question is: what should I do in a loop to merge (concatenate?) the chunks back in a .csv file after some processing of chunk (marking the row, dropping or modyfiing the column)? Or there is another way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to assume that since reading the entire file

```
tp = pandas.read_fwf(file, widths=widths, header=None)
```

fails but reading in chunks works, that the file is too big to be read at once and that you encountered a MemoryError.

In that case, if you can process the data in chunks, then to *concatenate* the results in a CSV, you could use `chunk.to_csv` to write the CSV in chunks:

```
filename = ...
for chunk in pd.read_fwf(file, widths=widths, header=None, chunksize=ch)
    # process the chunk
    chunk.to_csv(filename, mode='a')
```

Note that `mode='a'` opens the file in append mode, so that the output of each
`chunk.to_csv` call is appended to the same file.